# deep linking android app

Tags: android, indexing, deep-linking

hey I want to utilize deep linking/ app indexing concept in android app. for instance, by clicking on a button another app can open a custom activity of mine. I have seen many tutorials to open website from android app but i didn't see any for app content.

I tried this small code but actually not what i'm looking for.

```html
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);

                if (intent!=null) {
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }


                else {
                    //Log.d("NULL", "NULL");
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?    id=packageName");
                    Intent go = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                    startActivity(go);
                }
```

Comment: You can open your specific activity from another app.

Comment: Try to use in manifest
in your activity you want to open
<data android:mimeType="text/plain">
<data android:scheme="your scheme" />

Comment: what is my scheme?

Comment: its your scheme which should be handle on invoking applications side as well.